# Java nested parenthesis extraction

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have the below String

`((brand:("Levis") OR brand:("Sprit")) OR size:("XXL"))`

note the nested parenthesis.

I wanted to have a list that would hold the nested objects from smallest to biggest

like 
`[size:("XXL")][(brand:("Levis") OR brand:("Sprit")]`

I have the below code but I think it needs some tuning

Code output : `[("Levis"), ("Sprit"), (brand:("Levis") OR brand:("Sprit")), ("XXL"), ((brand:("Levis") OR brand:("Sprit")) OR size:("XXL"))]`

Expected output `[size:("XXL"),(brand:("Levis") OR brand:("Sprit")]`

```
class Test
{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<String> split = split("((brand:(\"Levis\") OR brand:(\"Sprit\")) OR size:(\"XXL\"))");
    System.out.println("Split: " + split);
}

 private static final String openBraces = "(";
 private static final String closeBraces = ")";

public static ArrayList<String> split(String s) {
    return split(s, openBraces, closeBraces);
}

private static class Start {
    final int brace;
    final int pos;

    public Start(int brace, int pos) {
        this.brace = brace;
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{"+openBraces.charAt(brace)+","+pos+"}";
    }
}

public static ArrayList<String> split(String s, String open, String close) {
    ArrayList<String> split = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Start> stack = new ArrayList<Start>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        int o = open.indexOf(ch);
        int c = close.indexOf(ch);
        if (o >= 0) {
            stack.add(new Start(o, i));
        } else if ( c >= 0 && stack.size() > 0 ) {
            int tosPos = stack.size() - 1;
            Start tos = stack.get(tosPos);
            if ( tos.brace == c) {
                split.add(s.substring(tos.pos, i+1));
                stack.remove(tosPos);
            }
        }
    }
    return split;
}
}
```

Comment: "*I think it needs some tuning*" - what's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @PM77-1 I have given the code output and expected output for that

Comment: Have you run your code step-by-step under debugger?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't make any sense.  The input clearly has 5 sets of parentheses, but your output only has two elements.  How exactly do you map the given input to that output?